# Render components without explicit dependency in ngModule

Tags: angular, ng-modules

I have a library called `foo` that contains an angular component called `FooContentComponent` that renders various types of content:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of contents">
  <ng-container *ngIf="item.type === 'text'">{{item.text}}</ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="item.type === 'math'">
    <foo-math [formula]="item.formula"></foo-math>
  </ng-continer>
</ng-container>
```

The `FooContentComponent` has its own `ngModule`. Similarly the `FooMathComponent` also lives in its own `ngModule`.

Here's the problem: i *don't* want to explicitly import the `FooMathModule` in the `FooContentModule`. Instead i want to leave it up to the application using the `foo` library to include the `FooMathModule` if the application wants to render math content. If the application doesn't want to render math content, it will not import the `FooMathModule` in its app module.

If i don't import the `FooMathModule` inside `FooContentModule` i will get an error from the compiler that it doesn't know `foo-math`. I can get rid of the error by specifying a custom schema in the `FooContentModule`, but then it still won't render the `FooMathComponent`.

Can i do this?

Comment: you cant do that as the FooMathComponent must be a declarative for your main.module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot target submodules from the app module's imports / declarations / whatsoever. However what you can do is using a static method like e.g. Angular router has its `forRoot()`

```
let imports = [standard imports here];

@NgModule({
  imports
})
export FooContentModule {
  // or call it forRoot if you want
  public static withAdditionalImports(additionalImports: any[]) {
    imports.push.apply(imports, additionalImports);

    return FooContentModule;
  }

}
```

and then you can use it in any module as

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FooContentModule.withAdditionalImports(FooMathModule)
  ]
})
export AnyModule {}
```

Note that if you do it at least once (e.g. in AppModule) it will be available everywhere so it would be enough to just import `FooContentModule` afterwards